# Jquery function onclick add class and remove class

Tags: jquery

I am doing jquery function to enable and disable input type text

the first function is working fine and change the class of the a href but the secound function that related to the new class is not working

here is the full code

http://jsfiddle.net/RcLgz/1/

Comment: sorry I just update the link right now

Answer (score 1):

i saw that u had not written `removeAttr` in your function and also use `live` function

```
$("a.add").live('click',function () 
{
    $(this).prev("input").css("opacity","1");

    $(this).prev("input").removeAttr("disabled");
    $(this).removeClass("add");
    $(this).addClass("edit");
});
```

i hope this ans will help you.. and let me know whether it works .

Comment: A little more explanation, `live` is deprecated, use `on` to bind to events.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use delegate event so the handler will apply to the changed DOM class:

```
$("div.row").on('click', 'a.add', function () {
    ...
});

$("div.row").on('click', 'a.edit', function() {
    ...
});
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RcLgz/6/)

Comment: @MohammadEreiqat. Is it working for you? I'm not sure I know what you want the output to be...

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/RcLgz/2/

**As of jQuery 1.7**, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

Here is the updated version:

http://jsfiddle.net/RcLgz/5/